# Dart How to filter a map by keys

Tags: flutter, dart

How to handle a map based on the keys?

If in my map the key is equal to my variable then I want to create a list which contains my map

If in my map the key is not equal to my variablecthen I want to create a list which contains 2 map objects with the key which has the nearest lower value and the key which has the nearest higher value

```
int myVar = 100;
 
  Map values = {
      "-900"  : 183,
      "-800"  : 164,
      "-700"  : 144,
      "-600"  : 124,
      "-500"  : 104,
      "-400"  : 84,
      "-300"  : 63,
      "-200"  : 42,
      "-100"  : 21,
      "0"     : 0,
      "100"   : -22,
      "200"   : -43,
      "300"   : -64
    };
```

For the exemple with myVar = 100, I want to have this:

```
int myVar = 100;
 
  Map values = {
      "100"   : -22,
    };
```

And if myVar = 112 for exemple I need to have the closest keys values. My result must be :

```
Map values = {
      "100"   : -22,
      "200"   : -43,
    };
```

I don't know how to do that.I had perhaps the idea to transform the map into a map list to be able to use the list functions.

```
List<Map> values = [
      {
        "arg1" :-900,
        "arg2": 183
      },
      {
        "arg1" :-800,
        "arg2": 164
      },
      {
        "arg1" :-700,
        "arg2": 144
      },
    // Some other values ...
    ];

 List newValues = values.where((c) => c['arg1'] == 100).toList();
```

is this the right method? How to transform my basic map if yes ?

**EDIT** : With the help of @jamesdlin I tried this but I have an error.

```
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {

  int myVar = 100;

  Map<int, int> values = {
      -900  : 183,
      -800  : 164,
      -700  : 144,
      -600  : 124,
      -500  : 104,
      -400  : 84,
      -300  : 63,
      -200  : 42,
      -100  : 21,
      0     : 0,
      100   : -22,
      200   : -43,
      300   : -64
    };
  
  print(values);
  
  Map<int, int> filter(int myVar, SplayTreeMap<int, int> values) {
    if (values.containsKey(myVar)) {
      return {myVar: values[myVar]};
    }

    int lowerKey = values.lastKeyBefore(myVar);
    int upperKey = values.firstKeyAfter(myVar);
    return {
      if (lowerKey != null) lowerKey: values[lowerKey],
      if (upperKey != null) upperKey: values[upperKey],
    };
  }
  
  print(filter(myVar, values));
}
```

I have this on dartpad :

```
: TypeError: Instance of 'JsLinkedHashMap<int, int>': type 'JsLinkedHashMap<int, int>' is not a subtype of type 'SplayTreeMap<int, int>'Error: TypeError: Instance of 'JsLinkedHashMap<int, int>': type 'JsLinkedHashMap<int, int>' is not a subtype of type 'SplayTreeMap<int, int>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `Map` is a `LinkedHashMap`, where iteration order is key insertion order.  For your use, you instead probably will want to use a [`SplayTreeMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html) where lookups are O(log n) instead of (ideally) O(1) (WRT the number of elements), but iteration order is in ascending order of keys.  This would allow you to use the [`lastKeyBefore(key)`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap/lastKeyBefore.html) and [`firstKeyAfter(key)`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap/firstKeyAfter.html) methods to find the previous and next elements if the key isn't directly contained.

I also would recommend that you use `int` as the key instead of a `String`.  If you use a `String`, the default ordering will be a *lexicographic* order (`"1"` < `"10"` < `"100"` < `"2"`).  You could supply you own comparison callback to `SplayTreeMap` to parse `String`s into `int`s when comparing, but doing so would still require parsing the same `String`s multiple times.  It'd be much simpler and more efficient to store `int`s as the keys directly.

Using `int` keys with a `SplayTreeMap`, it'd look something like:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart'; // For SplayTreeMap

Map<int, int> filter(int myVar, SplayTreeMap<int, int> values) {
  if (values.containsKey(myVar)) {
    return {myVar: values[myVar]};
  }

  int lowerKey = values.lastKeyBefore(myVar);
  int upperKey = values.firstKeyAfter(myVar);
  return {
    if (lowerKey != null) lowerKey: values[lowerKey],
    if (upperKey != null) upperKey: values[upperKey],
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.I understand what you explain me but I have an error. I EDIT my code.

Comment: @user2895656 Your `values` variable is created as a `Map`, which as I explained is a `LinkedHashMap`.  You would need to use [`SplayTreeMap.of`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html) to create a `SplayTreeMap` from an existing `Map`.  For example: `var values = SplayTreeMap.of({ -900: 183, ...});`.