# Locate a double-value in a Dart-Map between 2 elements

Tags: flutter, dart, linkedhashmap

I have got a Map like

```
Map<int, int> perc = { 
0: 0,
20: 1,
27: 2,
33: 3 
};

double whereIsThis = 13.52;
```

The Map is sorted by keys ascending.

I need to locate the two keys that surround the given double-value, e.g. to get an output like

> 13.52 is located between **0** and **20**;

How could I get those two elements?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see `ListExtensions.lowerBound*` methods

Comment: and in your particular case `lowerBoundBy` would be the easiest as `double` key is `Comparable`

Comment: Another option would be to use a `SplayTreeMap` instead of a `Map` and to use its [`lastKeyBefore`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap/lastKeyBefore.html) and [`firstKeyAfter`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap/firstKeyAfter.html) methods.  Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62478780/

Comment: @pskink Sorry, I am not able to implement this, as I am new to Flutter/Dart. Could you perhaps provide a concrete example?

Comment: `Map<int, int> perc = { 
0: 0,
20: 1,
27: 2,
33: 3 
};
print(perc.keys);
final index = perc .keys
.map((k) => k.toDouble())
.toList()
.lowerBoundBy<num>(13.52, (k) => k);
print(index);`

Comment: @pskink Thanks, but I get the error "The method lowerBoundBy isn't defined for the type 'List'"

Comment: `import 'package:collection/collection.dart';` - it is a built-in package

Comment: @pskink Ah - we are getting nearer :-) But how do I access the key? I can access the value with `print(perc.values.elementAt(index));` - but I need the key. Do you have any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: @pskink Got it - with `print(perc.keys.toList()[index]);` - Thanks for your help!

Comment: The problem with using `ListExtensions` is it requires you to first convert your map to a `List`, and when you have to convert a data structure into another data structure to do what you want, that's generally a good sign you aren't using the right data structure to begin with. The suggestion to use a `SplayTreeMap` would be preferable as it's designed to handle cases like this one.

Comment: Thanks, @Abion47, but I am not able to implement it with a SplayTreeMap. If you could give a concrete example for my problem I would be happy :-)

Comment: @BNetz There is a concrete example of how to implement a `SplayTreeMap` in jamesdlin's linked answer.

Comment: @Abion47 You are right, this would do. As the code is a bit complicated for me I will stick to the solution with the `ListExtensions` - although I absolutely see your point why you recommend the `SplayTreeMap`.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @pskink in the comments I was able to solve this:

```
Map<int, int> perc = { 
  0: 0,
  20: 1,
  27: 2,
  33: 3 
};
    
double whereIsThis = 13.52;
    
print(perc.keys);
        final index = perc.keys
            .map((k) => k.toDouble())
            .toList()
            .lowerBoundBy<num>(whereIsThis, (k) => k);
        int element = perc.values.elementAt(index);
      
int elementBefore = perc.values.elementAt(index - 1);
int elementAfter = perc.values.elementAt(index);
int keyBefore = perc.keys.toList()[index - 1];
int keyAfter = perc.keys.toList()[index];
print('$whereIsThis is between $keyBefore and $keyAfter');
```